# How to hide navbar before user logs into homepage

Tags: reactjs, navbar, show-hide

I need for the navbar to show when the user logs into homepage/site in ReactJS?

I tried to use a turnary method but it did not work successfully.

take a look at my code in github: https://github.com/Brian-Tech-20s/Music-Essentials.git (components/navbar.jsx)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please share the code of what you tried so far.

Comment: This question should be closed as it needs improvement and clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

The question has 2 things to be done

1. Storing the login data
2. Retrieving it to check the user existence

You can store the user logged in data to local storage / session storage and retrieve it when needed and with the help of use effect hook to check if the state of the login has changed to login or logout which can be set with the help of use state hook

Comment: So basically, the user registers their account then they login with the specified credentials that were saved through the local storage property. Upon login, I am able to see the navbar links(error: there was an empty navbar that was driving me crazy) that the user can access. However when the user chooses each nav link the navbar remains the same as I want but when they revisit a page or path the navbar goes empty again.